# Angular 1.6 Data not displaying when retrieved from service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I am trying to learn the new component syntax. If I set a user variable in the controller statically it works, I see the data on the page. If I try to get the same data from a service, the data is not displayed. I see the data in the then promise after I have assigned it to the this.user variable.

I created a plunkr to show you what I am trying.

http://plnkr.co/BGXesnKBmQGUlVH33jNa

```
angular.module('myWebApp', ['myModule']);

angular.module('myModule', []);

angular.
    module('myModule').
    component('myComponent', {
        controller: ['myService', function myController(mySvc) {
            mySvc.getUser().then(function (data) { // This gets data but does not populate view. Why?!
                this.user = {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    last: 'Shmoe'
                };

                console.log(user); // Populated with data from service
            });

            // Comment out above and uncoment this and it works!
            // this.user = {
            //     name: 'Joe',
            //     last: 'Shmoe'
            // };

        }],
        template: 'Hello, {{ $ctrl.user.name }}!',
    });

angular.
    module('myModule').
    factory('myService', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        function getUser() {
            // Simulate http get
            return $timeout(function() {
                return {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    last: 'Shmoe'
                };
            }, 1000);
        }

        return {
            getUser: getUser
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As llp pointed out, `this.user` is pointing to the function's `this`, so what you need to do is define `this` in a variable outside of the function and inside the controller like so ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KRv940WG23apubQvM92d?p=preview)):

```
angular.module('myWebApp', ['myModule']);

angular.module('myModule', []);

angular.
    module('myModule').
    component('myComponent', {
        controller: ['myService', function myController(mySvc) {
          var me = this;
            mySvc.getUser().then(function (data) { // This gets data but does not populate view. Why?!
                me.user = {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    last: 'Shmoe'
                };

                console.log(me.user); // Populated with data from service
            });

            // Comment out above and uncoment this and it works!
            // this.user = {
            //     name: 'Joe',
            //     last: 'Shmoe'
            // };

        }],
        template: 'Hello, {{ $ctrl.user.name }}!',
    });

angular.
    module('myModule').
    factory('myService', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        function getUser() {
            // Simulate http get
            return $timeout(function() {
                return {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    last: 'Shmoe'
                };
            }, 1000);
        }

        return {
            getUser: getUser
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Keep 2nd solution in your answer, using `$scope` inside `component` controller isn't valid as its not Angular 2 migration proof code..

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Comment: @PankajParkar Is it best practice to assign this to a variable (I've seen people use **vm**). Or is it best practice to use arrow functions?

Comment: @CodeWzrd if you find out the answer please share it here

Answer (score 1):

Because the `this` variable in the function within `then` is not the same as the `this` of `controller`, I suggest you to use the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will keep `this` unchanged to solve this problem:

```
angular.module('myWebApp', ['myModule']);

angular.module('myModule', []);

angular.
module('myModule').
component('myComponent', {
    controller: ['myService', function myController(mySvc) {
        mySvc.getUser().then((data) => { // Changed here!
            this.user = {
                name: 'Joe',
                last: 'Shmoe'
            };

            console.log(this.user); // Populated with data from service
        });

        // Comment out above and uncoment this and it works!
        // this.user = {
        //     name: 'Joe',
        //     last: 'Shmoe'
        // };

    }],
    template: 'Hello, {{ $ctrl.user.name }}!',
});

angular.
module('myModule').
factory('myService', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    function getUser() {
        // Simulate http get
        return $timeout(function() {
            return {
                name: 'Joe',
                last: 'Shmoe'
            };
        }, 1000);
    }

    return {
        getUser: getUser
    };
}]);
```

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w0312bNkrMTF3A1Cxjkt?p=preview)